# ► Will Microsofts CDN increase perfomance for linked HTML files?

Tags: content-editor-web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts

#### Content I pull in from a Document Library

[image]

This is just f.. slow..

#### Same site pulls in content from our own HTTPS server

[image]

#### Questions

- Will using Microsofts CDN solution par our own HTTPS server speed?

  > *from answer >* Yes
- My clients edit these HTML files using the built-in Office365 HTML Editor
  Is this Editor available on the CDN as well?

  > *from answer >* Not on the CDN,
  >   original files remain in the Tenant library and sync to the CDN (*update may take 15 minutes*)

**[also see comments in first answer]**

CDN resources

- https://dev.office.com/blogs/office-365-public-cdn-developer-preview-release
- https://blog.mastykarz.nl/publish-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-office-365-public-cdn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - yes.  The flow should work such that they edit the version in the library, and it will automatically update on the CDN.  Note that the CDN is public (although you can't get the list of files from akamai - you need to know the URL), so don't put stuff up there that you wouldn't want someone to see.

Comment: tnx. Waldeks instructions list filenames with GUIDs (per tenant I presume)  The MSDocs says this CDN is only accesible from SPOnline. But since the CDN location is discoverable; will tenant A be able to reconstruct filenames from tenant B and overwrite them? Or am i getting this wrong and is it a CDN * __per__* Tenant? If I am wrong, then the only benefit over our own CDN would be the CEWP editing with the Monaco editor part? Or are our own 15ms CDN downloads going to be beaten with 5ms  downloads from a Microsoft CDN location?

Comment: The CDN is Akamai, which may or may not have better performance than your own.  It likely has better geographical distribution, but I couldn't say for sure.  
The CDN isn't easily available outside of SPO.  As the document states, they check the referrer URL.  Of course, the referred URL isn't exactly a security measure - you can spoof it for a given request.
Tenant A can not conflict / overwrite a file from tenant B, as the host is incorporated into the URL.
It's a nice feature for people that aren't managing their own CDNs, and has some nice sync / integration aspects - but no magic.